# Cannot for the life of me get fb-like to show faces

Tags: html, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot get 'show faces' to work in the like box](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8660295/i-cannot-get-show-faces-to-work-in-the-like-box)

So I have the following 'page' I made for my site.

http://facebook.com/thenetipot.net

If I place this into the following code generator:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Unselect stream, but keep 'show faces' selected.

You will see I have 411 who have liked the site.

No faces show up. I have tried this over and over and I cannot get anything to show up.

The facebook documentation is really unhelpful too.